# how to bind multipart/form-data, Boundary=boundary in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I'm able to capture the packet on wireshark and get the image out of it, however when i bind it to my controller it doesn't. any help would be highly appreciated. my web api project is build on .net core 2.1 this is the packet trace from wireshark

[image: wireshark packet capture]

[image]

the following is my controller written in .net core 2.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include the request body in the question. Also, try updating the controller action method signature as `GetWantedPerson([FromForm] IFormFile faceCapture)`

Comment: @mohsin-mehmood the faceCapture is a json object, that element binds correctly. however, if you see the packet trace the images are the ones that are not binding. i need the image's to bind. GetWantedPerson([FromForm] IFormFile faceCapture) this doesn't work.

Comment: This was fixed, it was a bug from the device which was posting the data. once the firmware was updated it worked fine.